Почему не устанавливается postgreSQL
У меня проблема с установкой PostgreSQL 15.7-2-windowsx64.exe. Cтоит ОС Windows 7. При установке выскакивает следующее сообщение:
точка входа в процедуру setprocessmitigationpolicy не найдена в библиотеке kernel32.dll
Прошу отозваться тех, у кого была подобная проблема.
Спасибо.

PostgreSQL 15 не устанавливается на Windows 7, потому что в минимальных требованиях у неё Windows 10 (или может быть Windows 8.1, но точно не Windows 7).

Большое спасибо!
